# Google Analytics Event Tracking not working on Subdomain

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I recently set up a subdomain and added the GA global JS code to the top of each page:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=propertyID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'propertyID');
</script>
```

This has been working and has been tracking pageviews on my subdomain but it doesn't seem to be tracking onClick events.

The onClick is being rendered in the browser as such:

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Facebook Link Click', 'Clicks', 'Database Page');"
```

Checking the web console, I can see the event is NOT being fired when I click on the link (No GET request for GA).

When the page loads, it loads up the following from GA:

```
GET https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 54ms]
GET https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js [HTTP/2.0 304 Not Modified 21ms]
GET https://www.google-analytics.com/collect
```

I have the exact same code on my main site domain and it works but it just doesn't seem to be working on my subdomain, despite being the same code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was using the wrong syntax for tracking:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events#custom-events-and-parameters

```
gtag('event', 'aaa', {
  'event_category' : 'bbb',
  'event_label' : 'ccc'
});
```

Successfully fired the event.